# Doesn't work sharedpreferences between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have two fragments. In the first fragment I enter text and by sharedPreferences I pass this text to the second fragment. The second fragment is displayed but without text. When debug I see that on the second fragment in the method `loadText()` is null.But I don't know how to fix this error. UPD: In `editor.putString("saved_text", savedApiKey);` if I enter String value (for example `"hello word"` instead `savedApiKey` it works good.
the first fragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView textInFragment;
    private EditText enteredApiKey;
    private Button button;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "myPreferences";
    private String savedApiKey;

    public FirstFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

        textInFragment = view.findViewById(R.id.textInFirstFragment);
        enteredApiKey = view.findViewById(R.id.enteredApiKey);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        savedApiKey = enteredApiKey.getText().toString();
        saveText(savedApiKey);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SourceFragment newFragment = new SourceFragment();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
  private void saveText(String savedApiKey) {
        sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("saved_text", savedApiKey);
        editor.commit();
             }}
```

and the second fragment:

```
public class SourceFragment extends Fragment  {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "myPreferences";
    private String API_KEY;

    public SourceFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.source_fragment, container, false);
        TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(loadText());
        return view;
    }

    private String loadText() {
        sharedPreferences =getContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        API_KEY = sharedPreferences.getString("saved_text", null);
        return API_KEY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly use .apply(), not .commit() and getActivity() istead of getContext()

Comment: in this case doesn't work too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Bundle. Here's an example:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your Fragment, retrieve the data (e.g. in onCreate() method) with:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

and don't use Shared Preference like this.
actually use the Class with name of SharedPreference and make it singleton and use it anywhere you want without any problem.
sample code:

```
public class NameSP {
       private static NameSP spInstance = null;
       private Stirng Text;
       public static NameSP getSPInstance(){
       if (spInstance == null)
           spInstance = new NameSP();
       return spInstance;
       }
       
       public void saveInfo(){
           SharedPreferences sp = 
                  context.getSharedPreferences("nameSP",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
           editor.puStirng("text",yourStirng);
           editor.apply();
       }
       public void getText(){
         return this.Text; 
       }
}
```

in your fragment :

```
NameSP nameSp = NameSP.getInstance();
String Text = nameSP.getText();
```

this is just a guide , you need some methods more to load and clean and more to do. just search and keep going...

Answer (score 1):

When I call `saveText()` method in the `onPause()` method like:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        savedApiKey = enteredApiKey.getText().toString();
        saveText();
    }
```

it works

Answer (score 1):

There are no text in editText when `onCreateView` calling. You should call `saveText()` after your enter. For example in the button's `onClickListener()`.

But better use arguments for transmission data beetween fragments.